# Changing value of matrix and assigning value

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

The code below based on http://www.johnwittenauer.net/machine-learning-exercises-in-python-part-1/ works

```
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0, 0]))
def computeCost(X, y, theta, iterations, alpha):

    temp = np.matrix(np.zeros(theta.shape))
    m = len(X)
    theta_trans = theta.T
    for j in range(iterations):
        hyp = np.dot(X, theta_trans)-y

        term = np.multiply(hyp, X[:,0])
        temp[0,0] = theta[0,0] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term))

        term = np.multiply(hyp, X[:,1])
        temp[0,1] = theta[0,1] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term))

        theta = temp
        theta_trans = theta.T
    return theta
```

However, when I use theta directly instead of temp e.g. `theta[0,0] = theta[0,0] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term)))` and comment out the `theta = temp` I always get 0 and 0 for theta.

When I do a similar operation outside the function theta is changed. For instance,

```
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))
theta[0,0] = theta[0,0] - 1
print(theta)
```

theta shows as [-1 , 0].

Why is this type of assignment not working inside the function?

Comment: I don't understand your code: you have a loop but the iteration variable `j` is not used.

Comment: Can you also past the line where you call the function so that we can test it in the same conditions we do.

Answer (score 0):

A probable explanation: it is a problem of types (int vs float).

The assignment

```
theta = np.matrix(np.array([0, 0]))
```

creates a matrix of integers. There is some implicit conversion to integers when you assign directly its coefficients:

```
>>> m = np.matrix(np.array([0, 0]))
>>> m
matrix([[0, 0]])
>>> m[0,0] = 0.5    # float
>>> m
matrix([[0, 0]])    # no effect, 0.5 converted to 0
>>> m[0,0] = 1      # int
>>> m
matrix([[1, 0]])
```

In contrast, the `temp` variable is a matrix of floats (because `np.zeros` creates an array of floats when `dtype` is not specified), so the assignment of floats works as expected.

So just declare `theta` directly as a matrix of floats and you should be fine.